# IIS6 SSL Config - Have to log in twice (once for :80, once for :443)

Tags: asp.net, ssl, asp-classic, iis-6

I have a virtual folder containing an administration application, like

```
https://www.mysite.com/alpha
```

which requires SSL. In the IIS manager properties for the folder, under "Authentication and access control", Anonymous Access is disabled and "Authenticated Access" is set to "Integrated Windows authentication."

When I connect to the site in Chrome, I receive two login boxes. The first is from mysite.com/alpha:443, and the second is from mysite.com/alpha:80. Firefox appears to re-send my credentials for the second box so it is never shown.

Any ideas why I'd be required to log in twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require SSL for authenticated users on your website (for any reason), then the best solution is to always have your "Login" page on `https://`.  That way when they log in, they are instantly secure. The reason for this is because of the native design of SSL. It separates/secures it's self from the non secure version by not passing authentication states between `http` and `https`.

you will also have to write some logic to redirect returning authenticated visitors to the secure page (IE: visitors who can return authenticated from a cookie).

## EDIT:

Since your using windows authentication, it's probably easiest to simply redirect ***ALL*** incoming `http` traffic to `https`. This means your entire site will be over SSL and will be inaccessible via http (other than to redirect to https)

I wrote a [Blog Post](http://dotnetblogger.com/post/2008/12/03/ASPNET-Force-Website-to-use-WWW.aspx) on forcing a website to use WWW in the web address, but it can also be ported to forcing https.

Comment: Since I'm not using forms authentication, I'm not sure what you mean by "login page." ?

Comment: ah if you're using windows authentication, then the easiest thing to do would be to redirect all unsecure traffic to the secure page.  See my edit

Answer (score 0):

Yep,

The one uses SSL, the other not.
therefore, you are not allowed to share the credential cache from a Secure session, with the one of the unsecure session.

if you require SSL, then directly redirect the users to the SSL website.

Comment: "One but not the other" what? The entire folder requires authentication.